# In which menu should I put my plugin?

Tags: python, interface

I wrote a small Blender plugin, and I was wondering what the common location for plugins is in Blender? The plugin opens a small UI inside the viewport to perform an operation on the scene.

My priority would be:

1. A button in the viewport (visible in all modes)
   or
2. Adding it to the Window menu.

Is either of these options a common location for Blender plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's up to you but from what you say anything that relates to viewport probably fits in as VIEW3D panel. note you can append to existing panels to reduce clutter.